# Changing sound chip with ALSA

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I have a laptop with Intel audio card that `lspci` reports as

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

It is responsible for both Analog Audio (speakers, 3.5 mm jack) and HDMI sound (since my laptop has HDMI output) as reported by `aplay --list-devices`

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Obviously the audio card is configured and drivers are loaded. Media players, however, don't produce any sound. `pavucontrol` shows that there is output from the player - under playback tab, the slider which acts as a visual feedback is "bouncing". But under "Output devices" tab, the very same slider doesn't react at all. Under Configuration tab "Profile" is set to "Analog Stereo Duplex", which it should be. If I change the profile to "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output" the aferomentioned slider suddenly begins to bounce. It is now obvious to me that either ALSA or PulseAdio (I don't know which is to be blamed) recognize the HDMI chip as the default one. `alsamixer` gives me option to change sound card, but not it's chip.[image: alsamixer interface]

`pactl list` output

```
Module #0
    Name: module-device-restore
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute state of devices"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #1
    Name: module-stream-restore
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute/device state of streams"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #2
    Name: module-card-restore
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore profile of cards"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #3
    Name: module-augment-properties
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Augment the property sets of streams with additional static information"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #4
    Name: module-switch-on-port-available
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:


Module #5
    Name: module-udev-detect
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #6
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Argument: device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
    Usage counter: 0
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #7
    Name: module-jackdbus-detect
    Argument: channels=2
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "David Henningsson"
        module.description = "Adds JACK sink/source ports when JACK is started"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #8
    Name: module-bluetooth-policy
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau"
        module.description = "When a bluetooth sink or source is added, load module-loopback"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #9
    Name: module-bluetooth-discover
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #10
    Name: module-bluez5-discover
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #11
    Name: module-esound-protocol-unix
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ESOUND protocol (UNIX sockets)"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #12
    Name: module-native-protocol-unix
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Native protocol (UNIX sockets)"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #13
    Name: module-gconf
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "GConf Adapter"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #14
    Name: module-default-device-restore
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the default sink and source"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #15
    Name: module-rescue-streams
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is removed, try to move its streams to the default sink/source"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #16
    Name: module-always-sink
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Always keeps at least one sink loaded even if it's a null one"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #17
    Name: module-intended-roles
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically set device of streams based on intended roles of devices"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #18
    Name: module-suspend-on-idle
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is idle for too long, suspend it"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #19
    Name: module-console-kit
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each ConsoleKit session of this user"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #20
    Name: module-systemd-login
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each login session of this user"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #21
    Name: module-position-event-sounds
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Position event sounds between L and R depending on the position on screen of the widget triggering them."
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #22
    Name: module-role-cork
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Mute & cork streams with certain roles while others exist"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #23
    Name: module-filter-heuristics
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Detect when various filters are desirable"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #24
    Name: module-filter-apply
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Load filter sinks automatically when needed"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #25
    Name: module-x11-publish
    Argument: display=:0.0
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "X11 credential publisher"
        module.version = "5.0"

Module #26
    Name: module-x11-xsmp
    Argument: display=:0.0 session_manager=local/localhost:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/281,unix/localhost:/tmp/.ICE-unix/281
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "X11 session management"
        module.version = "5.0"

Sink #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 49145 /  75% / -7.50 dB,   front-right: 49145 /  75% / -7.50 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC269VB Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC269VB Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1b00000 irq 49"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel CougarPoint HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0269,10250504,00100100 HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900)
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1b00000 irq 49"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 8251 /  13% / -54.00 dB,   front-right: 8251 /  13% / -54.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 5206 /   8% / -66.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC269VB Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC269VB Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1b00000 irq 49"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel CougarPoint HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0269,10250504,00100100 HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority: 8900)
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700, not available)
    Active Port: analog-input-internal-mic
    Formats:
        pcm

Client #0
    Driver: module-systemd-login.c
    Owner Module: 20
    Properties:
        application.name = "Login Session c1"
        systemd-login.session = "c1"

Client #3
    Driver: module-x11-xsmp.c
    Owner Module: 26
    Properties:
        application.name = "XSMP Session on xfce4-session as 2c7bf982c-3f0a-4235-93e5-780d27ff15f0"
        xsmp.vendor = "xfce4-session"
        xsmp.client.id = "2c7bf982c-3f0a-4235-93e5-780d27ff15f0"

Client #10
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 12
    Properties:
        application.name = "pactl"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "29"
        application.process.id = "1707"
        application.process.user = "tichomir"
        application.process.host = "localhost"
        application.process.binary = "pactl"
        application.language = "C"
        window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        application.process.machine_id = "98bf0358e390486598b6233568214778"
        application.process.session_id = "c1"

Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 6
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1b00000 irq 49"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5400, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5460, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 300, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 360, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority: 8900, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo
```

Comment: What does `pactl list` have to say about all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following code to `/etc/asound.conf`

```
pcm.custom
{
    type plug
    slave
    {
        pcm "dmix:0,0"
    }
}

pcm.!default pcm.custom
```